# Búsqueda incompleta en JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy elaborando un programa para llevar un inventariado de mis colecciones. Para ello una de las funciones que utilizo es 'Buscar en archivo'. Se me ocurrió que los ítems los tendré guardados en un txt del siguiente modo:

```
    OBJETO    ||    CANTIDAD    ||    DESCRIPCIÓN

  Camisetas            12            Son talla X y de color Y
```

A la hora de Buscar se me ocurrió cargar todo el fichero en un ArrayList y eliminar la primera fila:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file)));
items.remove(0);
```

Querría saber como puedo buscar en el ArrayList con un término incompleto, por ejemplo, introducir 'Camiset' y que me busque la línea de Camisetas.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes recorrer el arraylist entero y comprobar si contiene el término que buscas usando algo como [`String.indexOf('camiset') > -1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-). Te dejo ahí el enlace a la documentación de `indexOf`. Obviamente necesitarás asegurarte de que las palabras están todas en minúsculas/todas en mayúsculas y que no haya acentos, o escribir todo siempre igual. Ahora te hago un ejemplo un poco más... *curioso*, un momento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, aquí te dejo un par, primero usando `streams` y luego con un método más *convencional*. En el código podrás encontrar explicaciones.

```
public class FilteringListExample {

    private List<String> categories;

    public FilteringListExample(){
        categories = Arrays.asList("Camisetas", "Cds", "Videojuegos", "Complementos", "Películas");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FilteringListExample example = new FilteringListExample();
        // Primero los ejemplos con streams
        System.out.println(example.getCategoriesByName("cam")); // Imprime [Camisetas]
        System.out.println(example.getCategoriesByName("c")); // Imprime [Camisetas, Cds, Complementos, Películas]
        // Ahora los ejemplos sin stream, el resultado es el mismo, pero este método tiene más código
        System.out.println(example.getCategoriesByNameWithoutStream("cam")); // Imprime [Camisetas]
        System.out.println(example.getCategoriesByNameWithoutStream("c")); // Imprime [Camisetas, Cds, Complementos, Películas]

    }

    /*
     * Este método usa streams para aprovechar que nos permite *iterar* y más aun, filtrar de manera sencilla.
     */
    public List<String> getCategoriesByName(String name){
        return categories.stream() // Primero convierto la lista en un stream
                /* Luego la filtro, esto permitirá "pasar" solo las que encajen con el filtro, es decir, para cada
                 * categoría de la lista la pasará a minúsculas y comprobará que encaje con el nombre pasado al método,
                 * también en minúsculas claro. Así nos evitamos problemas. Habría que pensar también en la posibilidad
                 * de eliminar los acentos para asegurarse, pero eso ya es cosa tuya :)
                */
                .filter(category -> category.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase()))
                // Finalmente, utilizo un collector predefinido para retornar una lista
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<String> getCategoriesByNameWithoutStream(String name){
        // Primero creo una lista
        List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        // Luego hago un bucle foreach, es decir, recorro las categorías una a una
        for(String category : categories){
            // Misma condición que en el filtro del método con streams
            if(category.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())){
                // La añado a la lista de filtradas
                filtered.add(category);
            }
        }
        // Y finalmente devuelvo la lista
        return filtered;
    }
}
```

---

[Aquí te dejo la documentación de streams de java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), que está disponible a partir de Java 8.

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo, con esto me soluciona muchísimas dudas